# Equivalent to "How to" in guides and the like

Tags: expressions, english-to-japanese, phrase-requests

What is an equivalent expression to "How to" that is used when searching/referring to guides, especially online?

Comment: Please provide us with an initial translation attempt, so the question can be answered.

Comment: Maybe 使い方 would work?

Comment: 説明書？せつめいしょ？An explanatory guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no equivalent. One way would be to change the verb where appropriate and make something like 寿司の作り方、漫画の描き方、ボスの倒し方, etc.

Or as the other answer said, use a generic word like 方法.

Answer (score 3):

When English nintendo website use “How to Charge the Controller”, In Japanese nintendo website use “コントローラーを充電する”. It has no meaning of “how to”, but this is a popular way. You can use “コントローラーの充電のしかた” too.

When you google “How to become a teacher?“ in Japanese, you should use “先生 なる 方法” or “先生になるには”.